# Подскажите как с другого класса добавить текст в TextArea JavaFX чтобы оно отобразилось в приложении?

Tags: java, javafx

Не могу понять как это сделать, уже все перепробовал. TextArea находится в классе BotOverviewController, а передаю данный с класса MainApp

вот код откудова передаю, это просто тестовая запись:

```
BotOverviewController botOverviewController = new BotOverviewController();

botOverviewController.setTerminalWeather("lol");
```

Вот код самого метода, что принимает значение и вписывает в TextArea:

```
public void setTerminalWeather(String terminalWeather){
    this.terminalWeather.setText(terminalWeather);
}
```

Постоянно ловлю ошибку Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Потому что надо вызывать тот объект контроллера, который привязан к сцене. А ты получается прсото создаешь пустой объект и пытаешься что-то у него там дергать

Comment: как всегда все очевидно. ))) Данное решение помогло